# Contact Data , Mobile Connect and Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, mobileconnect, contactbuilder

I have this scenario:

---

### | Keyword status DE                              |

### | Mobile (PK)       |    Status                  |

### | 34655555555       | active                     |

---

### | Entry Journey DE                               |

### | SubscriberKey (PK) | Email    |  Phone (PK)    |

### | test@test.com   | test@test.com  |34655555555  |

I have linked the Keyword status DE in contact builder as follows (1 to 1 on Mobile)
[image]

Now in journey builder, when I test this I thought I should be able to filter in the following way : Mobile equal Phone and Status equal Active

[image]

Unfortunately, it's taking the false path. Only if I leave "Mobile equal Phone" alone, it evaluates true.

How can I evaluate both conditions?

Answer (score 0):

It works when SubscriberKey = 34655555555

and SubscriberKey relates to Subscribers on Subscriber Key

It seems this is the way it's tied up to Contact Builder